# How to create an add-on for a game?

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to make a pop-up thing for a game (Among Us) that looks a bit like this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3lYU.png)
And ends up like this:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEPAX.png)
So that it's a little window on the side that pops out when you click it, then collapses when you click it again (It will have a function, but I think i'll be able to do that myself. I just dont know where to start). I'd prefer it if it was 'intergrated' into Among Us, so it opens with and on the same aplication, but otherwise I'm happy to have to open it manually each time and have it separate. I have Microsoft Visualizer if that helps.
Thank you.

Comment: So, what's your question, how to make add-on for or how to make right collapse view?

Comment: A right collapse view. I think.

Answer (score 0):

> A right collapse view. I think.

You could use [Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup?view=winrt-19041) class to implement above collapse view. Make a button as a opening indicator to open or close this Popup. And if you want it run smoothly, you could add Storyboard to animate above button indicator. For more please refer the following code.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" Color="Transparent" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Popup
        x:Name="RightMeun"
        Width="200"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=ActualHeight}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        IsOpen="False">

        <Popup.ChildTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Right" />
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Popup.ChildTransitions>
        <Grid
            Width="200"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=RightMeun, Path=Height}"
            Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Text="Hello" />
        </Grid>
    </Popup>
    <Button
        x:Name="MenuButton"
        Margin="0,0,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Content="&#xE102;"
        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ColorPaletteResources
                    x:Key="Default"
                    BaseLow="LightGreen"
                    BaseMediumLow="DarkCyan" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Button.Resources>
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="180" />
        </Button.RenderTransform>
    </Button>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Animation">
            <VisualState x:Name="Close">
                <Storyboard x:Name="CloseStoryboard">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightMeun" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MenuButton"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                        To="0"
                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MenuButton"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
                        To="180"
                        Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Open">
                <Storyboard x:Name="OpenStoryboard">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightMeun" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MenuButton"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                        From="0"
                        To="-200"
                        Duration="0:0:0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="MenuButton"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
                        To="0"
                        Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                </Storyboard>

            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (RightMeun.IsOpen)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Close", true);

    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Open", true);

    }
   
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. How do I make this a popup? Where do I put the code and how do I run it? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ArieCartner, I have make code sample [here](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SlideMenuTest), please check that for details.

Comment: @ArieCartner, Do you have any updates for this thread, and if the answer is helpful please consider mark it ,